# hybrid apps ctp 3 plugin installation

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I updated Visual studio to the newest update, deinstalled the old multi device hybrid apps ctp2 and installed the new version (ctp 3)

Now I can not add the facebook connect plugin to any project (all methods keep visual studio busy forever)

Hope I can figure this out quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can use config.xml to install Facebook connect plugin. Open config.xml, go to Plugins --> Custom and select Git. Enter Git url and hit arrow button and Add the plugin. Note that it takes a while to add the plugin depending upon your network connectivity.

[image]

Comment: well it keeps visual studio busy (i think download is finished it also adds the files to the project). I can install all other plugins but facebook connect does not succeed (not after 3 hours)